# CORS issue in same domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, same-origin-policy

I have an application which runs in my-dev.abc.com like URL in "abc" domain. (abc is not the real domain, it is for explaining the question).

When I tried to access the application portal.abc.com from the above mention application I'm getting following error message in the developer console and redirection won't happen.

```js
Failed to load https://portal.abc.com/: Redirect from 'https://portal.abc.com/' to 'https://portal.abc.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my-dev.abc.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Why is this CORS error happening even though both applications use the same domain name? How to resolve this? This redirection do from the Nodejs side. Client-side use angularjs. NodeJs redirection code snippet as shown below,

```js
function redirectApp(req, res) {
    res.clearCookie(COOKIES.USER_NAME);
    res.clearCookie(COOKIES.ROLES);
    res.clearCookie(COOKIES.EMPLOYEE_ID);
    res.redirect('https://portal.abc.com');
}
```

Comment: A subdomain is NOT considered the same domain, and for good reason.

Comment: When making up domains for use in a question, use `example.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Express, try settings allowed host to enable access control, I had the same issue with django and spent hours trying to figure it out.

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:9000'];
  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  return next();
});
```

Comment: is this should do in the https://portal.abc.com application or my-dev.abc.com application?

Comment: add your application domain in allowed hosts! in your case  my-dev.abc.com

Comment: my application is my-dev.abc.com and I'm trying to redirect to portal.abc.com . I need to add my-dev.abc.com  as allowed host in portal.abc.com. am i right here?

Comment: yes! that's what you need to do